# When to use MojoExecutionException vs MojoFailureException in Maven

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

The AbstractMavenMojo's execute method declares it throws two exceptions, MojoExecutionException and MojoFailureException. Throwing either results in the build stopping and the log displays an *almost* identical message in each case.

The message for MojoExecutionException is:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [exception text]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the message for MojoFailureException is:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [exception text]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When should you throw which exception and why?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It seems you should throw a `MojoExecutionException` if the problem makes it impossible to continue with the build, and use the `MojoFailureException` otherwise.

You can control the behavior for handing `MojoFailureExpections` when maven is run.

The following link details the difference: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html#writing-plugins-sect-failure
Broken link? Google search
[sonatype writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin writing-plugins-sect-failure](https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&q=sonatype+writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin+writing-plugins-sect-failure)

Comment: The link is broken. Try http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html#writing-plugins-sect-failure instead.

Comment: If I understand your answer (and the "Writing a Custom Plugin" section of the book), if the user provides an invalid configuration for my maven plugin I should throw `MojoExecutionException`?

Answer (score 5):

Throw a `MavenFailureException` if your build step failed but it could be ignored (for instance you may want to ignore failing tests).

Throw a `MavenExecutionException` if there is no way to continue - say you detected an unrecoverable condition like you were trying to compile and the project could not be compiled thus everything after that would be fruitless anyways.

`MavenExecutionException` will always kill the build whereas the behavior of the `MavenFailureException` is configurable.

The default behavior is to fail fast, i.e. the same behavior as the build error, which is most often what you want. You can alter the behavior by passing a command line flag:

`mvn -fae` fail at the end, i.e. every build step will be executed and you may experiencing subsequent failures if a stage fails, the whole build is only failed once every step has been executed.

`mvn -fn` do not fail. This is useful if you want to ignore for example a failing integration test but nevertheless `mvn deploy`.